# Dynamic Func/Lambdas

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I've got a method similar to this, which loops through one set of data and uses a value of the first object to find an object in a second set of data:

```
private void someMethod(IQueryable<RemoteUser> source, IQueryable<LocalUser> targetData) {

    // Loop all records in source data
    foreach(var u in source) {

        // Get keyvalue from source data and use it to find the matching record in targetData
        var keyValue = u.id;
        var object = from data.Where(o => o.id == keyValue).FirstOrDefault();    
        ...
    }

}
```

I'd like to make it more re-usable by passing in Func or using some other type of lambda and then convert the method to something I can use in a generic manner, i.e.:

```
private void someMethod<SourceT, TargetT>(IQueryable<SourceT> source, IQueryable<TargetT> targetData) {
    ....
}
```

What I'm not exactly sure on is how I can build a Func/Predicate/etc and pass it into the method. Keeping in mind that the "id" property will not be the same across all SourceT & TargetT properties.

To further explain, I'd like something where I can do this:

someMethod(RemoteUsers, LocalUsers, `something here to say 'find the user using the userId property'`);

someMethod(RemoteProducts, LocalProducts, `something here to say 'find the user using the productId property'`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most basic implementation of your `someMethod` routine:

```
private void someMethod<S, T, P>(
    IQueryable<S> source,
    IQueryable<T> target,
    Func<S, P> sourceSelector,
    Func<T, P> targetSelector)
{
    foreach(var s in source)
    {
        var sp = sourceSelector(s);
        var @object = target
            .Where(t => targetSelector(t).Equals(sp)).FirstOrDefault();    
        //...
    }
}
```

This implementation keeps the structure of your original code, but this comes at a cost. You are effectively doing `source.Count() * target.Count()` queries against your database. You need to drop the use of `foreach` when working with `IQueryable<>`.

In fact, whenever you start writing code with `foreach`, you need to ask yourself if you can use a LINQ query to build and filter your data and make the `foreach` loop only do the "simplest" tasks.

Here's how to make the method work better:

```
private void someMethod2<S, T, P>(
    IQueryable<S> source,
    IQueryable<T> target,
    Expression<Func<S, P>> sourceSelector,
    Expression<Func<T, P>> targetSelector)
{
    var query = source
        .GroupJoin(
            target,
            sourceSelector,
            targetSelector,
            (s, ts) => ts.FirstOrDefault());

    foreach(var @object in query)
    {   
        //...
    }
}
```

Note the use of `Expression<Func<,>>` and not just `Func<,>`. Also note the `GroupJoin` method call.

Comment: My source & target IQueryable data aren't coming from the same datasource, in fact the soure isn't even a database at all -- it's coming from a web service.  How does the call into someMethod look (what does P represent?)

Comment: @Chu - Since they are coming from a different source you don't need to use `IQueryable<>` and expressions. I'd still use the `GroupJoin` method and keep your `foreach` as light as possible. The `P` is just the properties (or rather their types) that you are joining on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Just for the sake of me understanding the selector portion, what do I pass into someMethod to as my `sourceSelector`?

Comment: @Chu - In your question you were joining on the `id` property. That's what goes in. `someMethod(source, target, u => u.id, o => o.id)`

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this logic works for an Entity Framework query, but it did not work for an OData query. OData simply translates it as filter=true...